# On acceptance of scientific paper

Tags: publications, paper-submission

Questions: what is the minimum requirement for a scientific paper to be accepted? How will i know what quality should my paper have to be accepted in a scientific journal? If i read the scientific papers of other scientists will it help me know the quality needed and how will i know?

Perhaps i have set as requirement for the acceptance very difficult and of very high quality papers. What should i do? If the paper is not accepted or is not suitable for acceptance could i keep it somewhere in the house and continue working on other papers and should i do the same for other papers that will not be accepted perhaps?

I want to make scientific contributions but perhaps my expectations for quality of the work and paper generally are too high.

I am an undergraduate student at a math department at a university.

Thank you.

Comment: That's why students have advisors or mentors. Find an academic who is happy to mentor you on this, they know this much better.

Comment: Thank you for your post Captain Emacs. I have tried to talk to my professors, but perhaps it is difficult to approach them and talk with them in a more free way expecially about making scientific papers and publishing them. In my first year at the university, i found that i had an academic advisor, i talked to her but perhaps i did not say the right things regarding my studies and making scientific papers. It is difficult these days to find her and talk with her, what should i do? Should i try to talk to other academics?  Academics know these things better than me. I need help i think,

Comment: please note that in very many cases people have the slightly different problem of overestimating the quality of their contribution. One does not simply want to “make a scientific paper”.  If you cannot get someone in your university to discuss your work, this is not an encouraging sign.

Comment: You need to cite three of the reviewer's papers. Good luck, because the reviewers are anonymous. - Serious answer: Most journals and conferences have some description of the requirements. They usually boil down to contributing something novel, which has worth for others and can easily be understood by the target audience.

Comment: Thank you for your post ZeroTheHero. I want to talk to persons who know about acceptance of math and physics papers from journals but it is difficult to approach and talk to them. It is like i am scared of what might happen if i talk to them. They have published papers in the past so they know i think.

Comment: Thank you allo. Novelty can be done i think if someone finds an open problem or open question. The part about the worth is where i do not know. Could you write some examples or one example so that i can understand what is needed?

Comment: An important criterion is that *you* think it is an interesting and/or useful contribution to the field.  There is no real point in publishing papers if they are of little interest or importance to anybody (and novel does not imply interesting or useful). The purpose of writing a paper is to communicate an information/understanding, but there has to be an audience.   Quality is *much* better than quantity in the long run, and publication is only the first step in acceptance by the research community, not the last.

Comment: I should add I have a large directory on my computer of half-baked papers (in both senses ;o) and a fair few papers in my publication list that might have been better left unfinished (not wrong, I hope, just not interesting or useful).  Choosing which topics to work on is an important skill to develop.

Comment: @plants In my view it is hard to talk about these things before some actual research work that may merit publication has been done. You write you are an undergraduate student. Are you already doing research/projects that potentially could lead to publication? If not, chances are that it's very hard at this point to get a qualified idea about what's required. Also you should have in mind that there are journals with very different levels and consequently very different requirements for publication.

Comment: Thank you Dikran Marsupial and Lewian for your posts. I know that if someone gets his degree, then a masters degree and then goes for a doctorate degree, while doing a doctorate degree he tries to do scientific research. I still do not have a degree in math. I want to try to learn what is accepted because if i try to answer a question which is considered not enough of value for publication or acceptance, then all that time i tried to answer it will be lost?

Comment: The best work by undergrad students I have seen were students who did *not* think it was publication-worthy.

Comment: If the fields or topics that are of interest for me are not those my professors work on, could i communicate with professors from other universities if they want to talk with me ,help me, advise me on makiing scientific papers? Or perhaps with professors from universities from other countries different than mine? Perhaps by sending them emails?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs indeed, it is not easy to learn to have that judgment, it needs both self-confidence *and* self-skepticism, I'm getting better at it after thirty years ;o)

Comment: @plants, the time isn't lost, especially at the start of your career you gain valuable skills and experience from the work even if it doesn't end up being published.  Aim to be as good a scientist/mathematician that you can be and the papers *will* follow.  Reading papers is a good way of finding out the requirements, but don't just look at top journals, sample some of the second-tier and some of the bad journals.  Even good journals publish obvious nonsense now and again, so look out for those as well, it helps understand the process.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial Indeed. If you enact robust self-confidence in carrying out the work and meticulous self-skepticism in publishing, you will not go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

#### Read existing papers.

In general, the first thing you need to do is to conduct a systematic review of the scientific literature, to make sure that you gain a solid understanding of the state of the art of the field, as well as any openings where more research can be conducted. One of the most fundamental tasks you have as a researcher is to convince your reader that your paper contains novel research; if you fail to do so, your paper will not be accepted to by a journal.

Additionally, reading lots of existing papers should give you an idea about how papers in your field are typically structured. Often, this is something like "Abstract, introduction, methodology, results, conclusions" but this might be different for mathematics.

Furthermore, if you're doing any human subjects experimentation, even something as innocuous as giving people a survey, you *must* obtain ethics approval from your university's IRB. Only the most predatory of journals would be willing to accept a paper that has not obtained ethics approval; again, this is the bare minimum for a paper to be accepted.

Finally, I would recommend that you work on improving your spelling and grammar. The point of a scientific paper is to communicate your results with the scientific community at large, and errors in these aspects will work to impair understanding, and a paper that is difficult to understand because of spelling and grammar is unlikely to be accepted.

Comment: @Buffy The question as posed: "what is the minimum requirement for a scientific paper to be accepted? How will i know what quality should my paper have to be accepted in a scientific journal?" I believe that I addressed these points. Perhaps I could make it more explicit, however.